# Composer and GIT Tags running slow

Tags: php, git, performance, composer-php

I have a project that depends on a handful of self made libraries. Whenever these libraries are released, I tag them. E.g: 1.22.82. The composer dependencies look like:

```
"company/library": "1.22.*"
```

There are quite a lot of tags now (hundreds). When running `composer update`, it takes very long, five to ten minutes. While at work it takes up about 10 extra megs per second and the process takes a constant 25% of CPU on my win machine (100% on a osx).

I have the impression there is something exponential going on in composer. Of course I can work around it and delete old tags but am wondering what the reason is.

(I started writing this question after doing a `composer update` and it is still running after ten minutes now, just to give you an idea.)

Comment: Meantime I deleted 99% of the tags and it's running smoothly again. However, there is room for improvement within the composer code that deals with tag analysis.